# Make ggplot2 write the order of magnitude of the axis label only once at the top

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, axis

I would like to make `ggplot2` write only the first part of the scientific notation onto the axis and then add a $x 10^n$ atop the axis for the order of magnitude. Is there a function to do this?

Here is a MWE with a hack to show what I mean:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = seq(1, 2, l = 10)*1000), aes(x,y)) + geom_line()
```

[image: not scaled y axis]

while I'd something like:

```
ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = seq(1, 2, l = 10)*1000), aes(x,y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, 2.05)*1000, label = c(1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2, "x 10^3"))
```

[image: scaled y axis]

As a side question, I have noticed that the axis label becomes quickly to close to the tick labels when they are large. Is there a way to set an automatic spacing in between them ?

Comment: What do you consider as "first part of the scientific notation"? What would the labels look like?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik you can look at post pointed by @beetroot where there is s scientific notation, and each label has the `x 10^n` written

Comment: @beetroot according to my previous comment, it's note a duplicate, I want to remove the `x 10^n` part and to make it appear at the top of the axis

Comment: yep, I misunderstoof your question at first, sorry.

Comment: Another (inferior to yours) hack : `p <- ggplot(data = dat , aes(x,y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=function(x) x/1000) +
  annotate("text", x=-Inf, y=Inf, label="10^{3}", hjust=1, parse=TRUE) ;
g = ggplotGrob(p) ;
g$layout$clip[g$layout$name == "panel"] = "off" ;
grid::grid.draw(g)`. (However, I think it would just look better if you added the 10^3 to the y-axis title.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more automated way to execute your hack, in case you want to use similar labeling rules for different data. It will figure out an appropriate power of 10 to use and apply that to the labeling:

```
y_breaks  = pretty_breaks()(data$y)
y_max_exp = floor(log10(max(y_breaks)))
y_breaks  = c(y_breaks, max(y_breaks) * 1.025)
y_labels  = if_else(y_breaks == max(y_breaks),
                   paste0("x 10^", y_max_exp),
                   as.character(y_breaks / (10^y_max_exp)))

ggplot(data, aes(x,y)) + geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = y_breaks, label = y_labels, minor_breaks = NULL)
```

[image]